# Any data structure in java that supports multiple keys - not map exactly

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I came a cross a situation where I need something like:

```
197 => 6   (1 year)
197 => 12  (2 years)
```

Want to add multiple products and their price, based on the years of subscription, the value varies.

I wonder if we have any data structure in java that supports duplicates keys (should behave like map but must support duplicate keys).

I can do by creating a class but just wanted to know if there is anything that supports this thing..It is more like a MAP but no the map since it needs to support multiple keys.

Comment: How can it behave like a map and at the same time have duplicate keys? What do you expect to get when you call `get(197)` in this case? An array? A list? And what when you try to delete an entry: `remove(197)`...which entry should be deleted? All of them? I think you didn't fully think this though.

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html

Comment: Looks more like a list than a map to me. Or possibly a map of arrays, e.g. `197: [6, 12]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can do it using existing libraries like guava. Here is a link to the interface `MultiMap` of guava library [link](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). Here an example on how to use it (taken from [here](http://tomjefferys.blogspot.it/2011/09/multimaps-google-guava.html)):

```
  Multimap<String, String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

  // Adding some key/value
  myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Banana");
  myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Apple");
  myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Pear");
  myMultimap.put("Vegetables", "Carrot");

  // Getting the size
  int size = myMultimap.size();
  System.out.println(size);  // 4

  // Getting values
  Collection<string> fruits = myMultimap.get("Fruits");
  System.out.println(fruits); // [Bannana, Apple, Pear]

  Collection<string> vegetables = myMultimap.get("Vegetables");
  System.out.println(vegetables); // [Carrot]
```

The second possibility is to create a `Map<String, List<Object>>` and manually handling the reference to the list of objects that you need to associate to a single key.

Comment: that's what I needed.

Comment: If you find that this is the right solution you can accept it with the green flag. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is MultiMap but this doesn't look like a good use case, You should use a `Map<Product, Map<Years, Price>>`

i.e.

```
197 => {
    1 year => 6
    2 years => 12
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an external library like guava, you could create your own.

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> hm = new HashMap();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
 ArrayList<String> li = new ArrayList();
 for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    li.add(j * i);
 hm.put(i, li);
}
System.out.println(hm.get(4));//[0,4,8,12....]
```